# Python interpreter suppressing newlines?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, macos-sierra

When I open a Python 3 interpreter, it is as if it's failing to add a newline after the output of a command. So instead of

```
>>> print(1)
1
>>>
```

I get:

```
>>> print(1)
>>> 1
  # there is a space here.
```

That's annoying, but something I can work with. I just hit <kbd>return</kbd> one more time and it gets me back to `>>>`. Unfortunately, this change stays in the same terminal window, so that when I exit <kbd>return</kbd> still does not add a newline. In bash, this results in:

```
(testing)[ 11:55:08 ] ~ > (testing)[ 11:55:09 ] ~ > (testing)[ 11:55:10 ] ~ > (testing)[ 11:55:10 ] ~ > (testing)[ 11:55:10 ] ~ > (testing)[ 11:55:10 ] ~ > (testing)[ 11:55:11 ] ~ > (testing)[ 11:55:11 ] ~ > (testing)[ 11:55:11 ] ~ >
```

You might imagine that this makes subsequent calls to `git` a tad impossible.

This happens in my Python 3 REPL, but not my Python 2 REPL (I also tried a Clisp REPL). I have `Python 3.4.4 (default, Mar  2 2016, 03:34:28)` installed with `MacPorts base version 2.3.4` on macOS Sierra.

I am more than willing to upgrade Python to 3.5, but before I do that I'd like to know if there is a reason this broke so that I can prevent it (or fix it) in the future.

Comment: You can try IPython.

Comment: That's strange. You're opening the interpreter through bash in some Terminal app, correct? Also, the `>>>` is called a prompt

Comment: This sounds like a terminal issue, especially since it persists after `python` exits. What is the output of `echo $TERM` at the shell prompt, both before and after you run `python`?

Comment: Does running `reset` solve the problem in the shell? (I don't expect it to solve the problem inside `python`.)

Comment: @KirillBulygin No doubt I can, but since this is localized to a specific version of Python I'd like to know why

Comment: It seems like it is [this issue](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807).  I'm quite certain of the duplicate question closing vote, but if you dispute that I'll be happy to vote to reopen.